# Is this a good grammar to xml schema?

Tags: xml, xsd, computer-science, grammar

If I have these rules:

```
PIZZA-->doughSAUCECHEESE

SAUCE-->marinara | bbq | pesto

CHEESE-->mozarella |
```

A pizza string is comprised of the literal 'dough' followed by 1 of 3 sauces.  It may end there(no cheese) or end with the literal 'mozarella'.
Here is my xml schema:

```
<xs:element name="pizza">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="doughLiteral" type="xs:string" fixed="dough"/>
    <xs:element name="sauce">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:enumeration value="marinara"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="bbq"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="pesto"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="cheese">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:enumeration value="mozarella"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:pattern value=""/>
        </xs:restriction> 
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs: complexType>
</xs: element>
```

I'm not sure if I specified the empty string correctly.  Also, I read that attributes are by default optional, elements are by default required though right, i.e. the schema above states there MUST be 1 sauce right?  Thank you.

Comment: I cannot the the relation between the grammar you defined and xml

Answer (score 1):

Elements by default are compulsory, to make them optional use `minOccurs="0"`.

You are missing a `xs:sequence` and the double `xs:simpleType` used in the `cheese` element definition is not correct.

The correct schema should be something like this:

```
<xs:element name="pizza">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="doughLiteral" type="xs:string" fixed="dough"/>
    <xs:element name="sauce">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:enumeration value="marinara"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="bbq"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="pesto"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="cheese" minOccurs="0">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:enumeration value="mozarella"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Having said that, as @seki correctly points out this schema defines an XML structure like:

```
<pizza>
  <doughLiteral>dough</doughLiteral>
  <sauce>marinara</sauce>
  <cheese>mozzarella</cheese>
</pizza>
```

not the plain text grammar you specify at the beginning of the question.